# How to separate one column to several?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
DataTable:
 id int,
 user_id int,
 field_id int,
 value varchar
```

DataExample:

```
id    user_id    field_id   value 
 1       1            1       'Peter'
 2       1            2       56
 3       1            3       100
 4       2            1       'Buzz'
 5       2            2       47
 6       2            3       120
```

I want to separate `value` column by `field_id` property:

```
Name    Age     Score
Peter   56      100
Buzz    47      120
```

I tried:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN field_id = 1 THEN  value
    END as Name,   
    CASE
        WHEN field_id = 2 THEN  value
    END as Age,
    CASE
        WHEN field_id = 3 THEN  value
    END as Score
    FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN DataTable t ON (t.user_id=u.id)
```

But got:

```
Name    Age     Score
Peter   null     null
null    56       null
null    null     100
Buzz    null      null
null    47       null
null    null      120
```

Any advises?

Comment: What are you doing with the data?  It might be easier and more maintainable to do your pivoting somewhere other than in the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `GROUP BY` to your query. `Name` is probably not unique you can consider grouping by `id`:

```
SELECT id, MAX(Name) AS Name, MAX(Age) AS Age, MAX(Score) AS Score
FROM (
  SELECT u.id
  CASE
    WHEN field_id = 1 THEN  value
  END as Name,   
  CASE
    WHEN field_id = 2 THEN  value
  END as Age,
  CASE
    WHEN field_id = 3 THEN  value
  END as Score
  FROM Users u
  INNER JOIN DataTable t ON (t.user_id=u.id)
) AS sub
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I believe you'll want `user_id` in the subquery and then GROUP BY that field. OTherwise, as written, you'll get nulls for each `name` and one NULL `name` record with oddball age and score values.

Comment: @lad2025: code snippet works but i got nulls in Name column